# How to mark a search box for chrome to detect and install in its "Other search engines"?

Tags: html, google-chrome, search

When I start typing in chrome the names of the following sites:

- Amazon
- Newegg
- Imdb
- Quora
- many others...

I can hit "tab" and chrome lets me search with that site's specific search engine. **What kind of HTML` do I add to a <form> to help chrome automatically detect a search box in a site I made?** Can I control the keyword chosen?

I found this [chrome doc talking about the feature](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95655&topic=14676&ctx=topic) from the user POV but not from the webmaster's. They call it "Search a specific site (tab to search)". Btw, google maps used to have this feature but recently it's died for some reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found an explanation about chromium at http://www.chromium.org/tab-to-search

Basically you need to link to an OpenSearch description document.

```
<head>
    <link type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" rel="search" href="url_of_osdd_file"/>
</head>
```

And this is the osdd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
    <ShortName>Search My Site</ShortName>
    <Description>Search My Site</Description>
    <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="http://my_site/{searchTerms}"/>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

Comment: Does Chrome or any other browser follow this, or is it for Chromium only?

Comment: I don't know, haven't tested it. I was happy enough to find documentation for it. Though I do assume it works in Chrome if it works in Chromium.